# Delaying networkState.StartGame

Tags: xna, client-server

I am working on a project and have a problem with the packetreader/packetwriter classes.

Basically The game loads and allows players to create or join sessions. When they have selected either of those options it goes into a lobby screen. This part works fine. In the lobby screen they are able to choose between 3 different options and then select to start the game when they are ready. The options detail what texture to load to represent the player and are simply different colored squares at this point. Once all players have hit start it goes to a gameplay screen where the game is played. If the slower computer is the host it works perfectly fine. However if the faster computer is the host it loads into the gameplay screen before the slower computer has a chance to finish running through all of its updates that was passed through the PacketReader and PacketWriter objects.

Is there a way to wait until all players have finished reading the data from those streams before it continues on?  I am using code from the Client Server demo http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/network_cs and a demo that project called NetworkStateManagement (was found by a friend couldn't remember the link) as bases for my reasoning and logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of what I'm getting at. In Halo Reach say there are 5 people in a lobby players 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If player 1 changes a piece of his armor it updates on each other player's screens both in the lobby and in the actual match. In my game each player is represented by a color square. I want it where if player 1 selects red and player 2 selects blue it changes accordingly. the lobby screen is composed of a list of each player and 5 menu options. The first menu option is Start Game and the rest of the options are the different color's the player can choose from. When Start game is selected it toggles the players isReady state that is used in the NetworkSession object. Here is the code I have in my Update function that runs if the player is the host and everyone has marked themselves as ready.

```
else if (networkSession.IsHost && networkSession.IsEveryoneReady) 
{ 
     // Before starting the game make sure the server has gone through and updated. 
     // Also go through each player and make sure they have been updated so that no information is left in the packetReader and packetWriter 
     if (packetReader.Length > 0) 
     { 
         UpdateServer(); 
     } 
     // Read any incoming network packets. 
     foreach (LocalNetworkGamer gamer in networkSession.LocalGamers) 
     { 
         if (gamer.IsHost) 
         { 
             ServerReadInputFromClients(gamer); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
             ClientReadGameStateFromServer(gamer); 
         } 
     } 
     // The host checks whether everyone has marked themselves 
     // as ready, and starts the game in response. 
     networkSession.StartGame(); 
}
```

Comment: *'if the faster computer is the host it loads into the gameplay screen before the slower computer has a chance to finish running through all of its updates that was passed through the PacketReader and PacketWriter objects.'* - how have you confirmed this?

Comment: I have run the program using my desktop which is a slower computer (takes longer to start up programs and compile and run the code) as the host and my laptop as a non-host player and it runs perfectly. When I run it the other way around the desktop crashes while the laptop continues on. And it always shows that it is crashing while reading data out of the PacketReader.